# Import Magento1.9 product data only for specific store view

Tags: csv, magento, magento-1.9

I am struggling to update product name, description, and short description only for my Arabic store view.

here is my CSV file format

[image: CSV File]

here is my product in Default store view before import

[image: Default Values]

After importing the CSV here is what I get in Default Values, as you can see default values get changed while I only targeted `arabic` in _store column of the CSV.

[image: Default values after import]

And the Arabic store values remain unchanged as shown below.

[image: Arabic values unchanged]

Could you please point out what I am missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: are you trying magmi ?

Answer (score 1):

Magento will always treat the first row of the product as the attributes of the default store view. That means, if you need to do import only for specific store views, you will need to have at least two rows: (1) first row for default store view, and (2) second row for the specific store view.

In your case, you will need at least two rows which specify the import attributes for default store view and Arabic store view.

Based on my experience, it's always best to do import in a clean Magento catalog to avoid this kind of issue. But if you can't, you can begin with Magento's generated CSV export and do your edits from there.